# Is it possible to examine vector tiles contents besides displaying them with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vector-tiles

I would like to play with VersaTiles vector tiles, and display them but also examine the contents of each displayed tile as data. Is there a way to do that?

Vector tiles URL : https://tiles.versatiles.org/#0.95/0/0

Styles : https://tiles.versatiles.org/styles/colorful.json

Comment: Can you post the link to the vector tiles you want to use?

Comment: For instance https://tiles.versatiles.org/styles/colorful.json from https://tiles.versatiles.org/

Comment: A nice question. However, can you be more concrete regarding the preferred approach for examining the vector tiles' content/styles, via GUI or programmatically, what do you expect as an output? Besides the great answer suggested by @user30184, one can also check the [JSON style](https://github.com/versatiles-org/versatiles-style/releases/tag/v3.7.0) file, which simply says how to render and what fields to show of which element defined by [the OSM tag](https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To some extent, you can study the data by saving tiles locally. For example https://tiles.versatiles.org/tiles/osm/4/9/7.

Drag and drop the downloaded file "7" into QGIS and you'll see layers.

[image]

At least some layers have also attributes.

[image]